# iMacros changes the source code when I save it

Tags: compare, imacros

I have just downloaded iMacros, but it changes the source code when I do a 'SAVEAS', compared to when I manually do a 'file' -> 'saveas' -> 'web page HTML only' in Firefox.

How can I make the iMacros 'saveas' be the same as my manual FF save?

My iMacros code is:

```
URL GOTO=http://www.?????? 
SAVEAS TYPE=HTM FOLDER=C:\xampp\htdocs FILE=name.htm
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this workaround:

```
SET myLink http://www.?????? 
URL GOTO={{myLink}}

SET S "var doc = window.document; var elt = doc.createElement('a'); elt.id = 'myA'; elt.href = '{{myLink}}'; doc.body.appendChild(elt); undefined;"
URL GOTO=javascript:{{S}}

ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=C:\xampp\htdocs FILE=name.htm
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:{{myLink}} CONTENT=EVENT:SAVETARGETAS

URL GOTO=javascript:{doc.body.removeChild(doc.getElementById("myA"));undefined;}
```